# can not find my location on my device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I open it on my device and then it closes only this is what I get in the logcat
I'm using firebase I do not get the coordinates in my database
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.android.uberr, PID: 4254
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.android.uberr/com.example.android.uberr.DriverMapActivity}: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: GoogleApiClient must not be null
GoogleApiClient must not be null

> what i am doing wrong?

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class DriverMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(getApplicationContext()!=null){
            mLastLocation = location;

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));



            String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driversAvailable");

            GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
            geoFire.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driversAvailable");

        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
        geoFire.removeLocation(userId);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share code.

Comment: try adding  GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect(); to on create